# AJAX POST to a DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I need to load a DIV with a seperate PHP file which then displays totals without refreshing the screen.

My problem is that I need to POST the data as the vars are too long for GET requests. So, essentially I need to do the same as the working code below with POST rather than get:

```
function displayTotals(d){

   var url = "./include/display_totals.inc.php?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=" + d;

   $("#TotalsDIV").load(url);
}
```

Note: The vars are not in a form so I can't serialize it. I need to be able to assign them seperately.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post("URL TO PHP.PHP", {VAR1: 'VAL', VAR2: 'VAL'}, function(data){
 $("div").append(data);
});
```

Use the Jquery post call as above

Comment: Thanks to you all, I used this one but I am sure the rest worked too. The only change I made was .html(data) instead of .append(data)

Answer (score 1):

It's evidently in the jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
function displayTotals(d){

   var url = "./include/display_totals.inc.php";

   $("#TotalsDIV").load(url,{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:d});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [jQuery `post()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)?

Unless I am misunderstanding the question:

```
$.post("./include/display_totals.inc.php.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```